# ¿Como guardar y extraer un BitmapImage o WriteableBitmap de una base de datos UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

Intento convertir un  `BitmapImage` en un  `Byte[]` para almacenarlo en una base de datos de SQL server, el problema es que no encuentro la manera de extraer esos bytes y convertirlos de nuevo a  `BitmapImage` o `WriteableBitmap` para posteriormente usarlos en un control, Eh escuchado que se utilizan `IRandomAccessStream`. Estos son mis intentos.

```
public static async Task<byte[]> ToByteArray(this IRandomAccessStream accessStream)
    {
        var stream = accessStream.AsStreamForRead();

        byte[] array = new byte[stream.Length];

        await stream.ReadAsync(array, 0, array.Length);

        return array;
    }

    public static IRandomAccessStream ToRandomAccessStream(this byte[] array)
    {

        return array.AsBuffer().AsStream().AsRandomAccessStream();
        //           InMemoryRandomAccessStream result
        //= new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        //           await result.WriteAsync(array.AsBuffer());
        //           result.Seek(0);
        //           return result;
    }

    public static async Task<BitmapImage> ToBitmapImageAsync(this IRandomAccessStream accessStream)
    {


        accessStream.Seek(0);
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(accessStream);
        return bitmap;
    }

    public static async Task<BitmapImage> ToBitmapImageAsync(this byte[] array)
    {
        return await array.ToRandomAccessStream().ToBitmapImageAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static public async Task<BitmapImage> LoadBitmapAsync(byte[] bytes)
        {
            if (bytes != null && bytes.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
                {

                    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                    await stream.WriteAsync(bytes.AsBuffer());
                    stream.Seek(0);
                    await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream);

                    return bitmap;

                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        static public async Task<BitmapImage> LoadBitmapAsync(IRandomAccessStreamReference randomStreamReference)
        {
            var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            try
            {
                using (var stream = await randomStreamReference.OpenReadAsync())
                {
                    await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream);
                }
            }
            catch { }
            return bitmap;
        }
```

Comment: Bienvenido, comentar solo código es considerado de baja calidad, por lo mismo, podrías agregar una explicación de tu código?